# Stored Data in Keychain?

Tags: ios, ios7.1

I am saving my data in keychain.

if someone have root access of iPhone then is it possible to decrypt stored encrypted data in keychain?

Answer (score 0):

The worse case is jailbroken (rooted), even then there are only two options: a brute force attack against the Keychain key or against the user's passcode (PIN).

The first attack is essentially not possible.

To attack the user's pin requests must be made to the Keychain and that is rate limited by the Keychain, there is no other way to brute force against the user's passcode. Apple has promised that as CPU speeds increase the minimum time between passcode attempts will not decrease. The user needs to choose an extended passcode.

Note: people who jailbreak do so with the tradeoff of security but content owners probably still do desire security.